# problems with EaselJS getCacheDataURL

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I have some problems with using `getCacheDataURL`. This function work correctly in chrome but dont work in IE 10 and Firefox. I do so:

```
var cont = new createjs.Container();
var cont.cache(0,0,50,50);
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(cont.getCacheDataURL());
var stage = new createjs.Stage();
stage.addChild(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using toDataUrl, just use `cont.cacheCanvas` as the source, which creates a Bitmap that points to the canvas created by the cache. This is much faster than exporting the canvas to an image and using that image.

```
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(cont.cacheCanvas);
```

Additionally, the second line looks wrong:

```
var cont.cache(0,0,50,50);
```

`var` is probably doing nothing in this context.

Comment: on the second line `var` is my typing error. Thank you!